# Is powered delivered to an Incandescent light bulb changing with time?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, power

Initially, when the current starts flowing the temperature of the filament is less and thus resistance is less. So, more current flows through the bulb and the power delivered to the bulb is more. As, time passes and the filament starts glowing at a steady rate its temperature has increased which in turn has increased its resistance. So, less current flows through it and thus less power is delivered.

Is this the case? Please help me understand the situation.

Comment: Power depends on current **and** voltage.  Your assumptions are not necessarily correct.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I think we can safely ignore the voltage sag caused by one lightbulb versus a country-wide electric supply.

Comment: @MSalters  :-)  but maybe he's just got a C-battery!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to model the exponential growth of luminosity when you flick a light on](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95672/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is indeed the case, although the timescale is quite short by human standards. The filament is up to operating temperatures quite quickly.